# Disable Default Password Policy with portal-ext.properties

Tags: liferay

So i want to disable the required password change for fist time users.
I am running this local, to test this out until it works, as i want it.

I have made an `portal-ext` file that contains the following:

```
company.security.auth.type=screenName
users.screen.name.allow.numeric=true
terms.of.use.required=false
users.reminder.queries.enabled=false
passwords.default.policy.changeable=true
passwords.default.policy.change.required=false
users.reminder.queries.custom.question.enabled=false

users.last.name.required=false
users.email.address.required=false

passwords.toolkit=com.liferay.portal.security.pwd.RegExpToolkit
passwords.regexptoolkit.charset=0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghilmnopqrstuv
passwords.regexptoolkit.length=8
passwords.regexptoolkit.pattern=.+
```

As you can see, i have already set the `passwords.default.policy.change.required` to `false`.
But when i login with a first time user, it still shows the "change password" screen, which it should not.

It NEEDS to be done from the `portal-ext` file, and not the control panel, since this file is going on multiply servers,
so its disabled on all. And future servers as well.

Anyone have an idea whats wrong, or what I'm needing ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A further look at the liferay forum, i found a post about this, where a liferay staff posted this answer:

> Unfortunately the default password policy is not something you can
>   configure in portal(-ext).properties so there's no way to disable it
>   that way.

It's therefore impossible to get the result I'm looking for.

[Source](https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/12947123)

Comment: If you have found a  work around for this please do share.Im also have a requirement like Im creating users into ldap server using java code and importing them from ldap to liferay.So i  have to disable the new password  screen.

Comment: If i find a solution or liferay comes up with one, i will share it

Comment: now the change password screen doesnt show up when the user first time logged in with my current portal-ext configuration.Strange to be honest! Let me know if you want me to share it so that it might help you

Comment: That sounds great if it works! I would love to see what you've done, and see if that works for me as well. So yes, please share if you don't mind :-)

Comment: I have added the portal-ext.properties as an answer .Check whether it helps or not

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll try and see if i can get it to work as well. Appreciate it!

Comment: I've added an explanation to the linked forum post: You can change the password policy through portal-ext.properties *before first startup*: When Liferay first populates the database, it will write the default password policy to the database, and that's when these settings will be taken into account. Once the password policy has been written to the database, the policies are no longer consulted.

Answer (score 2):

when you add the property

> `passwords.default.policy.changeable=true`

It means allow user to change his password. On other hand when you set the property,

> `passwords.default.policy.change.required=false`

It implies its mandatory for the user to change the password. Here, you are setting it false. So we should not get 'Change password' screen.

I would suggest try to remove changeable property from the portal-ext.property file.

> `passwords.default.policy.changeable=true`

Comment: Thanks for your respond, but i have already tried that. when 'passwords.default.policy.change.required' didn't work, i tried to add 'passwords.default.policy.changeable=true' to the file aswell to see if that should do it, but i get the same result

Comment: Did you restart the server after changing the portal-ext.property file? Or try to add the configuration in portal-setup-wizard.property if you are using liferay version 6.1+

Comment: I tried to restart the server. And have also tried to set 'setup.wizard.enabled' to true, to set it all up again. That didn't work either. Is there another way i can config. the setup wizard ?

Answer (score 2):

> Blockquote
>   So i want to disable the required password change for fist time users. I am running this local, to test this out until it works, as i want it.
>   Blockquote

If you want to diseable change required for users password, just use this portal propertie:
passwords.default.policy.change.required=false

Answer (score 1):

@Patrick R This is the portal-ext i use . See the screenshots of new user login in.Im not sure whether this will solve your issue or not.Please cross the check the properties.

```
 #jdbc.default.jndi.name=jdbc/LiferayPool
    jdbc.default.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    jdbc.default.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/lportal?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useFastDateParsing=false
    jdbc.default.username=root
    jdbc.default.password=root

    soas.database.name=soasdb
    soas.database.username=root
    soas.database.password=root
    soas.database.hostname=localhost
    soas.database.connection=jdbc:mysql://localhost/soasdb?user=root&password=root
    soas.servicepartner.name=localhost



    json.service.auth.token.hosts.allowed=127.0.0.1
    json.service.auth.token.enabled=false
    jsonws.web.service.public.methods=*
    jsonws.servlet.hosts.allowed=127.0.0.1


    users.screen.name.validator=com.liferay.portal.security.auth.LiberalScreenNameValidator


    ldap.base.provider.url= ldap://localhost:389
    ldap.base.dn= dc=soas,dc=schoox
    ldap.security.principal= cn=admin
    ldap.security.credentials= blahblah
    auth.pipeline.pre=com.liferay.portal.security.auth.LDAPAuth

    ldap.auth.enabled=true
    ldap.auth.required=false
    ldap.password.policy.enabled=true
    ldap.users.dn= dc=soas,dc=schoox
    ldap.groups.dn= dc=soas,dc=schoox

    ldap.import.enabled=true
    ldap.import.interval=1
    ldap.import.on.startup=true

    ldap.import.method=group
    ldap.import.group.search.filter.enabled=true


    ldap.import.user.password.enabled=false
    ldap.import.user.password.autogenerated=false
    ldap.import.user.password.default=userPassword


    ldap.user.mappings=screenName=uid\npassword=userPassword\nemailAddress=mail\nfirstName=givenName\nlastName=sn
    #ldap.user.mappings=screenName=cn\npassword=userPassword\nemailAddress=mail\nfirstName=cn\nlastName=sn
    #ldap.user.mappings=screenName=displayName\npassword=userPassword\nemailAddress=mail\nfirstName=givenName\nlastName=sn

    ldap.group.mappings=groupName=cn\ndescription=description\nuser=member
    ldap.import.user.search.filter=(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)
    ldap.import.group.search.filter=(objectClass=groupOfEntries)
    ldap.auth.search.filter=(uid=@screen_name@)




    axis.servlet.hosts.allowed=
    axis.servlet.https.required=false
    company.security.auth.type=screenName
    search.container.show.pagination.top=false
    setup.wizard.enabled=false
```

**When a new user login**

[image]

**Terms and condition**

[image]

**Password Reminder**

[image]

**Successfull login**

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately it's still not working for me. But I'm glad it's working for you though.

Comment: can u try cleaning db?

Comment: passwords.default.policy.change.required=false. and changable=true are they still exists in your properties? if yes comment out that and try

Comment: Still don't work :-( but i have made a pastebin with the portal-ext here http://pastebin.com/yZEqaCS7 can you see if i'm missing an important setting or have set something wrong ? Also i have outcomment the xxx.change.required=false as you said

Comment: Which version of plugin sdk are u using?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [Olaf Kock](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13447/olaf-kock). I'm currently working on a Liferay DXP 7.2 upgrade from 6.2 and I'm facing the same issue of having Change Password screen on first-time user login through Kerberos SSO.

I went through the addUserWithWorkflow method of Liferay codebase in UserLocalServiceImpl and I've also verified the database table for handling the Password Policy which has these columns for configuring Password Changeable and Change Required settings. During addUser for the first-time, passwordReset column in the Liferay table - User_ is set as 1 (true) if the columns in Password Policy is set to 1 (true). This is the reason why we see Change Password prompt after user login.

I understood that the only way to change this configuration through portal-ext.properties is when the Liferay is setup for the first time before the server startup otherwise, a DB patch has to be applied in the Liferay table - PasswordPolicy to set 0 (false) for the below columns.

> changeable and changeRequired